# how do i convert this object C code to swift. I'm stuck

Tags: class, swift, model

/* this is my ModelFlightScheduleDetail.h code , this code is written is objective c , how can i convert this code to swift
*/

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GRUFlightScheduleResponse : NSObject

@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *strService;    
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *strResultType;    

@property(nonatomic,retain) ModelFlightScheduleDetail *FlightScheduleDetail;    
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *mArrFlightSchedule;    

+ (id) objectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
@end

@interface ModelFlightScheduleDetail : NSObject

@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *strFlightNumber;    
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *strCarriage;    
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *strArriveDeptType;    


+ (id) objectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;

@end
```

Comment: Downvoting this because this is something you can easily read up on by just opening the most basic swift example, you haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much Obj-C but im fairly fluent in swift, will give it my best try.

The variable declarations such as

@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *strService;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *strResultType;

can be written is swift as:

```
var strService:NSString!
var strResultType:NSString!
```

using the same format, any other variable declarations can be written in this way.

should something look like `@interface ModelFlightScheduleDetail : NSObject`

This is a class declaration and in swift can be written in the following way:

```
class ModelFlightScheduleDetail: NSObject {code}
```

Any @end that you see doesn't need to be there in swift, the end of a method/class is determined by the curly braces as above, contain all relevant code within those braces.

As for the `+ (id) objectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;`

unfortunately I'm not sure how to translate this; but I hope I helped with the other code.

Good luck in your programming ventures!

Answer (score 0):

Her You go ->

Put this code, on the correct place. and Initialise it before playing with it.

```
     import Foundation


    // All Global Variables

    var GRUFlightScheduleResponse : NSObject!
    var strService : String!
    var strResultType : String!

    var FlightScheduleDetail : ModelFlightScheduleDetail!
    var mArrFlightSchedule: NSMutableArray!


    var strFlightNumber : String!
    var strCarriage : String!
    var strArriveDeptType : String!

    // Common Function

    func objectWithDictionary(dictionary :  NSDictionary) -> AnyObject
    {
return YourAnyObjectHere
    }

    // init Method

   init(fromDict dict: NSDictionary) {
  //
}
```

Comment: initWithDictionary should be a init method, with dictionary parameter. objectWithDictionary should be a static or class method.